# Javascript console printing not working when assigning splice of array to itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I do this:

```
var testArray  = ["a","b","c"];
console.log(testArray);
console.log("size:" + testArray.length);
```

I this this printed in my console:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
size:3
```

Which is good. But now when I start splicing with this:

```
var testArray  = ["a","b","c"];
console.log(testArray);
console.log("size:" + testArray.length);
testArray = testArray.splice(0,1);
```

This happens to show in my console:

```
["b", "c", undefined × 1]
size:3
```

So first question is why does it mess up my printing of the array even though the splice was after the printing? The size is shown correctly but the "a" is gone and I get an undefined at the end.

So what I wanted to do was to remove the first item in the array. Basically a shift. So I do this:

```
var testArray  = ["a","b","c"];
console.log(testArray);
console.log("size:" + testArray.length);
testArray = testArray.splice(0,1);
console.log(testArray);
console.log("size:" + testArray.length);
```

And this is what gets outputted:

```
["b", "c", undefined × 1]
size:3
["a"]
size:1
```

Not only did the size decrease by 2, it deleted everything but the "a". What is going on?

Comment: Splice returns the "spliced" array. In this case, you're setting `testArray` to the result of the splice, which is the array `["a"]`

Comment: @Shmiddty Ah thanks! I guess I was using the spliced wrong then.

Comment: yes, javascript's splice is similar to the way PHP's array_shift works, you remove one, and are returned that one.

Comment: You could do something like `testArray = testArray.splice(1);` If you want to simply remove the first item.

Comment: The console issue is; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Comment: Interesting about the console issue. But thanks everyone. Solved all my questions!

Comment: splice will produce very odd results if you need to keep the index.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Dont assign testArray to itself. Simply do:

```
var testArray  = ["a","b","c"];
console.log(testArray);
console.log("size:" + testArray.length);
testArray.splice(0,1);
console.log(testArray);
console.log("size:" + testArray.length);
```